# Using Threads and ConcurrentBag in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm building a simple port scanner in C#. I already have the port scanning functionality, and the user passes the number of threads to use, and the range of IP address. So, what I have at the moment is that I have parsed the range and created a `ConcurrentBag` that contains all the IP addresses in the range. I also have an array of threads. So, it partially looks like this:

```
var ipsInRange = IPAddressRange.Parse(range);

Thread[] hostThreads = new Thread[(int)threads];
ConcurrentBag<IPAddress> ips = new ConcurrentBag<IPAddress>();
foreach (var ip in ipsInRange)
{
    ips.Add(ip);
}

IPAddress address;
while (!ips.IsEmpty)
{
    if (ips.TryTake(out address))
    {
        PortScanner ps = new PortScanner(address);
        ps.Scan();
    }
}

// I want to assign each thread one IP address, create a new PortScanner 
// instance as above, and scan the IP. I want to delete the scanned IPs 
// from the bag. When the thread finishes with scanning, I want to assign 
// a new one to it. I want to continue like this until the bag is empty, 
// i.e. all the IPs are processed.
// So, simply I want to scan multiple IPs at the same time, using the above 
// thread array and the ConcurrentBag containing list of IPs.
```

Though, I haven't used `Threads` and `ConcurrentBag` before, and what I want to achieve is written above in the comments. Any idea how can I incorporate the above threads into the app?

Comment: Search for resources on multi-threaded network programming to help educate yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) rather than managing threads yourself. It leads to short and readable code and you don't need to deal with neither threads, nor ConcurrentBag.

If all IP addresses are known before port scan begins (i.e. you don't need to add/remove IP addresses during port scan), code can be as simple as this:

```
var ipsInRange = IPAddressRange.Parse(range);

var options = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5// Set number of IP addresses to be processed concurrently
};

Parallel.ForEach(
    ipsInRange,
    options,
    (address) => { PortScanner ps = new PortScanner(address); ps.Scan(); });
```

If you need to support scenario where the list of IP addresses could be modified (from other thread) while port scan is in progress, you would need to wrap `ipsInRange` collection in [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1), but from your question it seems to me that it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

As I see solution:

1. Create [blocking collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) with IP-addresses
2. Create several Tasks, that takes IP from coolection and scan it.

   ```
   var bc = new BlockingCollection<string>();
   //...
   bc.Add(ip); //add addresses from another thread, or smth else
   //...

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       Task.Run(()=>
       {
           var address = bc.Take();
           PortScanner ps = new PortScanner(address);
           ps.Scan();
       });
   }
   ```

You have 10 threads, that scan addresses and they will wait, while collection can give them next element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this, but apparently it doesn't work. I noticed that it executes the for loop, but it just increments `i` and goes out. It comes to the `Task.Run` part, and skips everything inside it. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: @tinker it does not skip. It start new thread and execute code inside `Run` method

Comment: It finishes very quickly, and it doesn't even print to console anything, but normally when my program runs it prints stuff to the console. Secondly, if I put a breakpoint let's say in `address`, it doesn't stop there. Previously I was doing similar code as yours, but I was using `List<Task>` and then doing `Task.WaitAll()` at the end. It was again taking some time to finish, and printing stuff to the console.

Comment: @tinker I don't know, where do you call this code, if you use console app, add `Console.ReadKey()` to prevent exiting main thread. Or keep main thread alive by another method

Comment: Yes, I'm using a console app, and calling that inside the Main function.

Comment: @tinker add `Console.ReadKey()` at the end